# Let $X_1\sim \text{Bin}(n_1,p)$, $X_2\sim \text{Bin}(n_2,p)$ independent. Find the distribution of $X_1|X_1+X_2=m$.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

> Let $X_1\sim \text{Bin}(n_1,p)$ and $X_2\sim \text{Bin}(n_2,p)$ independent.
>
> a)Find the distribution of $X_1|X_1+X_2=m$
>
> b)Calculate $E[X_1|X_1+X_2=m]$

I know that $X_1+X_2\sim \text{Bin}(n_1+n_2,p)$
\begin{align*}
P(X_1|X_1+X_2=m)&\overset{\text{indep}}=\frac{P(X_1=x_1P(X_2=m-x_1)}{P(X_1+X_2=m)}\\
&=\frac{\binom{n_1}{x_1}p^{x_1}(1-p)^{n_1-x_1}\binom {n_2}{x_1-m}p^{m-x_1}(1-p)^{n_2-m+x_1}}{\binom{n_1+n_2}{m}p^m(1-p)^{n_1+n_2-m}}\\
&=\frac{\binom{n_1}{x_1}\binom{n_2}{x_1-m}}{\binom{n_1+n_2}{m}}\\
&\sim\text{Hypergeometric}(n_1+n_2,n_1,m)
\end{align*}

b)I know that $$E[X_1|X_1+X_2=m]=\sum_{x}x P(X_1|X_1+X_2=m)$$

but since that I have the conditional distribution, this expectation not would be
$$\frac{m\cdot n_1}{n_1+n_2}$$

Forgive me for any mistake, been a while since I study probability

Comment: HINT: Have you looked at what the mean of a hypergeometric distribution? Since you've already identified that $X_1\mid X_1+X_2 = m$ is hypergeometric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\checkmark$ Mostly okay.   Excellent work; but presentation needs care.

**Typo alert:** That should be: $\mathsf P(X_1\color{blue}{=x_1}\mid X_1+X_2=m) ~=~ \dfrac{\dbinom{n_1}{x_1}\dbinom{n_2}{\color{blue}{m-x_1}}}{\dbinom{n_1+n_2}{m}}$.

However, that is indeed the *Hypergeometric Distribution*; which is that of the count of successes in a sample of size $n_1$, drawn without bias from a population of size $n_1+n_2$, which contains $m$ successes.

Thus the expectation is known to be:

$$\mathsf E(X_1\mid X_1+X_2=m) = \dfrac{n_1\cdot m}{(n_1+n_2)}$$

---

PS: You should include the support of $X_1$.